# Proof that something is a subspace given it's a subset of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, finite-fields

Hi I'm having trouble with this homework question:

"Let $F^2 = {0, 1}$ denote the field with 2 elements 0 and 1.
Let $V$ be a vector space over $F^2$. Show that every non-empty subset $W$ of $V$ which is closed
under addition is a subspace of $V$."

So I know I need to show that it's closed under vector addition (which in the question it is), that it contains the zero vector and that it's closed under scalar multiplication. I was going to argue along the lines of since $V$ is a vector space and $W$ is a subset of $V$ both scalar multiplication and existence of the zero vector are satisfied because if they hold in the bigger thing $V$  then they must hold in the smaller thing $W$. I think this is flawed though because then I don't see why they'd give me that is closed under vector addition as I could argue the same way for that.

Comment: What possibilities do you have for scalar multiplication?

Comment: It would just be 0 and 1 so if test the two cases. For 1 the vector is just itself for zero the vector goes to the zero vector?

Comment: @Thomas: Exactly. Of course, that only works after you have shown that the zero vector is in $W$. Hint: What happens if you add a vector to itself?

Comment: If it hadn't given me that the vectors were closed under vector addition could I still show its a subspace or is there too little information?

Comment: @Thomas: If you hadn't been given closedness under addition, then all you would have left is that it is a nonempty set. But obviously not every non-empty set is a subspace (except if $V=\{0\}$). For example, take a set containing a single vector other than $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you here why having the $\vec{0}$ element is true because we're using $F^2$:

If we were trying to use $\mathbb{N}$ as a subset of the vector space $\mathbb{R^1}$ - it is closed under addition but surely not a vector space!

Here it holds true because for every vector $\vec{w} \in W$ :

$$ \vec{w} + \vec{w} = (1+1)\cdot \vec{w} = 0 \cdot \vec{w} = \vec{0} $$
and because $W$ is closed under addition, we get that $\vec{0} \in W$ and for each $w\in W$ , $-w = w \in W$ so you have the $\vec{0} $ element and for each vector you have the negative of it in $W$. Also,

$$ 1 \cdot \vec{w} = \vec{w} \in W$$
$$ 0 \cdot \vec{w} = \vec{0} \in W$$

Now you have all of the properties to call it a vector space.

QED

Comment: "I'll show you here why having the $\vec 0$ element is true only because we're using $F^2$" — Actually it follows for any field of characteristic $\ne 0$ (which obviously includes all finite fields, and in particular $F^2$). So the "only" here is misleading.

Comment: On the other hand, for general fields, you'd need to get closedness under scalar multiplication from additional conditions, and once you have closedness under scalar multiplication, you get having the $\vec 0$ for free, as for any $\vec v$ you have $\vec 0=0\vec v$. Indeed, it iscommon to define $\mathbb N$ to include $0$, and then you indeed have $\vec 0$ included in your example, yet $\mathbb N$ of course still isn't a subspace of $\mathbb R^1$ (indeed, even having negatives don't suffice, as $\mathbb Z$ demonstrates).

Comment: celtschk, you're correct about the first comment and I edited, but I think your second comment is unnecessary, I think that from the context it was well understood that I defined $\mathbb{N}$ without $0$ ...

Comment: Obviously you misuderstood my comment. I didn't criticise you for not including $0$ in $\mathbb N$, but I used the example of $\mathbb N$ including $0$ as an illustration that in the general case, $\vec 0\in W$ is not a sufficient additional condition for $W$ being a vector space.